# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on Ubuntu (Zorin OS)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I have tried a lot to get rid of this. But how can I solve this?

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Output:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Same result for this. Can't reset password.

While trying to enter into mysql then giving this error:

```
sudo mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try
grep 'A temporary password is generated for root@localhost' /var/log/mysqld.log |tail -1
and test password

Comment: Will you please give proper steps?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).